# How to change folding settings in Vim-LaTeX?

Tags: vim, vim-latex, code-folding

I am new to Vim so I apologize if the answer to this questions is too obvious. I wanted to try Vim-LaTeX, and I like it so far after a couple of days using it.

---

**This is the problem that I have:**

I cannot find a way to configure my `.vimrc` file for custom folding options. As of now, every time I open a TeX file, my preamble, sections, and most of the environments are folded. This can be very annoying, especially when I want to look through code of a large files. Based on that, I have a couple of questions that I will list below.

- Pressig `za` in normal mode will unfold the line I am on, and `\rf` will refresh folding of the entire document. Is there a command that will unfold the whole document?
- How can I configure `.vimrc` or any other file so that I completely turn off folding for all TeX documents?
- How can I customize Vim to fold only what I want? As of right now, I would only prefer to fold the preamble in all my TeX files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `:help fold`:

> zR  Open all folds.  This sets 'foldlevel' to highest fold level.

From `:help 'foldlevelstart'`:

```
'foldlevelstart' 'fdls'   number (default: -1)
      global
      {not available when compiled without the |+folding|
      feature}
  Sets 'foldlevel' when starting to edit another buffer in a window.
  Useful to always start editing with all folds closed (value zero),
  some folds closed (one) or no folds closed (99).
```

So you can add the following to your .vimrc:

```
set foldlevelstart=99
```

From `:help fold-methods`:

```
There are six methods to select folds:
manual        manually define folds
indent        more indent means a higher fold level
expr          specify an expression to define folds
syntax        folds defined by syntax highlighting
diff          folds for unchanged text
marker        folds defined by markers in the text
```

So you'll have to investigate the `expr` method

##### A word of advice for new vim users about plugins

From personal experience, when I was new to vim I started by installing a lot
of plugins very early on. This turned out to be a (common) mistake since
when beginning to learn vim, plugins can lead to you not learning a lot of vim's
default features. In the end I went through my .vimrc and commented out
everything I didn't understand (which was nearly all of it) and then only added
each setting/plugin back after researching and understanding what it was doing.
This helped me a lot. To be clear I'm not arguing that plugins are bad! I use
many of them now, I'm suggesting that plugins can be make it harder to learn
vim well at the start.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Also, I agree with your advice completely. I've been using Vim for about a week now, and so far my .vimrc file only has whatever was necessary for Vim-LaTeX and I added relative number lines and English spellcheck.

Comment: @Vladimir I'm glad it helped, I've been using vim for a couple of years now and am still learning new things all the time. A couple of great sites with video tutorials are http://derekwyatt.org/vim/tutorials/index.html and http://vimcasts.org/